# Need make pure css menu with 3 level

Tags: html, css

I make pure css menu with 2 levels .But now I need to make it 3 levels .I tried many time but not working for me . here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CW5b7/) .
I don't need any jquery code, just pure css .

CSS

```
#menu {
    width: 980px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    border-top: dashed 1px #d8d8d8;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
#menu ul.Mainmenu {
    width: 996px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#menu ul.Mainmenu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #860300;
    margin-right: 16px\9;  /* IE8 and below */
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
}
#menu ul.Mainmenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #860300;
}
ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 190px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -transition: opacity 0.5s;
    z-index: 100000;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
ul li ul li {

    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 190px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    line-height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
ul li ul li a {

    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #820B06;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul li ul li:hover a {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
ul li:hover ul {

    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i added sample CSS Menu with level 3. Please check and let me know. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks.

```css
.third-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
```

```html
 <ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Offices</a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">New York</a>
        <ul class="third-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have also put together a live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/4ScFz/400/ that's available to play with.

Answer (score 1):

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/R3YeR/)

css

```
#nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
    }
  #nav ul li{
margin:0;
padding:10px 20px;
position:relative;
height:20px;
line-height:20px;
background-color:#EEE;
     }
    #nav > ul > li {
float: left;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
background-color:#CCC;
    }
    #nav li > ul{
visibility:hidden;
width:200px;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:200px;
border-left:1px solid #000;
    }
    #nav > ul > li > ul{
top:50px;
left:0;
    }
    #nav li:hover{
background-color:#999;
    }
    #nav li:hover > ul{
visibility:visible;
    }
```

html

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2-1</li>
            <li>Level 2-2
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 3-1</li>
                    <li>Level 3-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```